# How to add image in textfield

Tags: jquery, css

i am making a site in which when user add answer in textbox and click on submit button then if it is right answer,it will appear as green otherwise as red and image of valid and invalid will show on text-box respectivley... Please help me .. i have following lines of code..

HLML code:

```
<body>
    <div id="content">babababababababababa.
        <input type="text" id="ans1" />y
        <input type="text" id="ans2" />asasasasasa
        <br />
        <br />
        <input type="text" id="ans3" />rtrtrtr
        <input type="text" id="ans4" />sddddddd
        <input type="text" id="ans5" />iuyerr
        <input type="text" id="ans6" />a la
        <br />
        <br />situación actual y
        <input type="text" id="ans7" />cccccc
        <input type="text" id="ans8" />skdodksodsdkss
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <div align="center">
            <input type="submit" onClick="check()" />
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS code:

```
     #ans1 ,#ans6 {
      background:#FFFFFF url(xx.png) 4px 4px ;
      background-position: right top;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      padding:4px 4px 4px 22px;
      height:22px;
      } 
     input[type="text"],input[type="submit"]
                {
      border:none;
      border:1px solid black;
      border-radius:5px;
      width:143px;
      height:23px;
      background:red;
      background:#EEEEEE;
      font-weight:bold;
      }
        body
                  {
      background:#BBBBBB;
      margin:auto;
      padding:100px;
      }
     #content
      {
       border:2px solid #AAAAAA;
       border-radius:15px 15px;
       padding:20px;
       }
```

Javascript Code:

```
   function check() {
        var ans1 = document.getElementById("ans1").value;
        var a1ns1 = document.getElementById("ans1");
        if (ans1 == "Crear") {
            a1ns1.style.color = "green";
        } else {
            a1ns1.style.color = "red";

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to change the image of textbox with jQuery, you can do something like this:

```
$('#ans1').css('background-image', 'url("url-to-your-image")');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add image in text field by the css background-image.

```
input{
  background-image: url(your-image-url);
}
```